# Cannot figure out how the .pch file is referenced by the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, precompiled-headers, pch

Sorry about the novice question, but in this simple [iOS tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) I could not figure out where in the project (in `Info.plist` or somewhere else) is stated that the file `HelloThere_Prefix.pch` relates to the other files. I understand that it links to some libraries, but could not understand how it is referenced by the other files. I only see the `.m` files referencing their respective `.h` files and nothing else. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project build settings there is a setting titled "Prefix Header" which specifies the path to your .pch file.  You can use whatever name you want as long as it matches this setting.